Torsional constant of a built up (welded) section
If I have two same size RHS, made out of same material with same Torsional constant and welded together, is the resultant Torsional Constant just the summation of the two?

Joined at 90 degrees? inline? side by side? And who did the welding? Lloyds rated or Youtube expert?

No. If the two RHS tubings are the same length and welded longitudinally end-to-end, perfectly correct.
The new torsional constant will be half of each piece's torsional constant because, under the same torque, the assembly will twist twice.
$$K_{initial}=\frac{\tau}{\theta}$$
$$K_{final}=\frac{\tau}{2\theta}= \frac{1}{2}K_{initial}$$
